# Use config Url instead of config.ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, config

In my `config/environment/development.rb,` i have

```
config.ip: 'http://localhost:3000'
```

In my `config/environment/production.rb,` i have

```
config.ip = 'http://52.74.70.227'
```

I want to use something like `config.url = 'http://example.com'`
So when someone recives an activation email link from me the link shows  `http://example.com/abc` intead of `http://52.74.70.227/abc`

Comment: please try this hope it will work. Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'http://localhost:3000'

Comment: @P_M will this change my ip to url in production

Comment: why can't you define this config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost:3000"} and in production config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "example.com"}

Answer (score 0):

in `config/environment/development.rb` define

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "localhost:3000"}
```

in `config/environment/production.rb` define

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "example.com"}
```

for more info check here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html